# How can I merge these selected faces?

Tags: faces

[image: faces merging]

I made that shape using boolean modifier and two cylinder.
But two face has been created after modifier has been applied.
I am unable to merge these two faces.
I tried "Dissolve faces" command but it did not work.

Comment: Why would you want to merge them? You should subdivide them further, so that you don't have "ngons" (faces with more than 4 vertices).

Comment: I want to do it to simplify the shape. When you want to change height of that edge you have to select both faces for example. Besides, if I import these kind of shapes to my application these separate faces creates unwanted reflections when light etc. applied to the scene. But I must add more edges like you suggested  instead of getting rid of them to get a better views at scenes, hmm.

Comment: Incidentally, a Face, in Blender, internally. is defined by a single loop of edges, anticlockwise when looking down the face's normal. So, topologically, wherever a face has a hole, it will have at least one edge connecting the hole to the boundary, to satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delete them and create nice geometry by bridging the edge loops instead(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> -> <kbd>L</kbd>):

[image]

This way you will avoid possible shading errors with automatic triangulation of concave n-gons. You can then select the face loop by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ click, or select one face and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>-><kbd>C</kbd> for selecting Co-planar faces, or you could use select linked flat faces function:

[image]

You could assign a shortcut to that by rightclicking it and choosing assign shortcut.

Comment: This answer solves my problem not the one considered asked before and answered.

Comment: OK, I voted to reopen the question so it's visible to others again since it seems to be useful. It would need more votes to be reopened though. And it sort of looks like a duplicate so it might stay closed, but I am glad my answer helped.